# What does 'masurault' mean?

Tags: histoire

I'm researching my French ancestry and found an entry for my 7th great grandfather in Emigration Rochelaise. Google Translate can translate every word except for 'masurault'.
Here's the phrase it's in:

> "Le 12 janvier 1641, Nicolas Pinel acquiert de Daniel Gombault un masurault situe a La Rochelle"

Even just googling the word only returned two entries that couldn't be translated. They are:

> Baillette  par  Jean  Béchet,  écuyer,  seigneur  de  Genouillé  et Fief-Béchet,  paroisse  de  Sainte-Sonline  (Sainte-Soulle),  d'une  terre Tun  masurault  en  ce  lieu.

and

> deux  maisons  en  la  rue ou  allée  par  où  Ton  va  de  la  porte  Ghaslon  à  la  tour  Carrée,  au long  des  murs;  une  maison,  rue  de  TAumosnerye;  une  maison
> ou  masurault,  tenant  au  chemin  de  la  porte  Ghaslon  à  la  chapelle de  Grâce

I'm guessing it has something to do with real estate, maybe? Maybe it's something specific to La Rochelle? Even my French teacher wife's huge Larousse dictionary doesn't have it.
If anybody knows what it is, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some kind of country/rustic house and/or house with surroundings (fields, uncultivated etc.) or estate. I'll provide the following sources for someone else who is more familiar with the topic/history in France to expand on it:

*Masureau*: *maison rustique* ([DMF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/masureau))
*Masurel* -> *Masurault* -> synonymous with *masure* ([Godefroy](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/masurel))
*Masurau*: *maison rustique* etc. ([FEW](https://lecteur-few.atilf.fr/index.php/page/lire/e/166030))
Generally, see [*masure*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/masure) from latin *mansura* « tenure domaniale, manse » (TLFi)

So the TLF says that a *masure* is a very poor shabby cottage. The suffixe *eau* (*ault* is just a variant) is a diminutive suffix (*souris* → *souriceau*, *arbre* → *arbrisseau*, etc), adding *ault* to *masure* makes the building even shabbier or smaller. The word *masure* is not much used nowadays. We can also note a regional difference, in the west of France, especially in Normandie, there are what is still called [*clos-masure*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clos-masure). [Les masures, fermes typiques du Pays de Caux](https://www.geneacaux.fr/spip/spip.php?article425).

Comment: J'avais tout de suite pensé à _masure_ effectivement.

Comment: Aussi, _masurault_ rappelle _hameau_.

Comment: I was surprised to see "masure" being equated to shabby. Turns out that I'm from Normandie, and as per [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/masure/49796) the local meaning there is different. As for the suffix eau/ault, it doesn't mean shabbier, just smaller. A "masure" evokes something (relatively) big in my mind, not a mansion, but comfortably big for a family with multiple children, while I'm guessing "masurault" would refer to something of more ordinary dimensions, perhaps even on the small side.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Indeed, it's special to Normandie, as specified in my edit to the wiki. And the [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/masure) also has this regional meaning. But the first meaning is « Édifice, maison en ruines; habitation misérable, délabrée. ». It is written that eau is a diminutive suffix, not that it "means" shabbier.

Comment: @None: I'm mentioning that it's "smaller" only (for ault) because the current answer says "even shabbier or smaller".